# SQL Query to select lockers with room for package

Tags: sql, postgresql, associations

I am building a smart locker reservation system with the following Postgres tables:

```
CREATE TABLE lockers (
  id serial primary key
)

CREATE TABLE doors (
  id serial primary key,
  locker_id integer NOT NULL,
  size integer
);

CREATE TABLE packages (
  id serial primary key,
  locker_id integer NOT NULL,
  size integer
);
```

A package can be reserved to a locker by setting the `locker_id` column of the package. The packages will eventually get a `door_id` when they are delivered to the locker, but that is out of the scope of this question. For now, I am just interested in the reservations, and this setup gives me a lot of flexibility (e.g. if a small package is reserved to a locker that has a single large door at the time of reservation, but the locker has smaller doors available at the time of delivery, I don't need to rewrite a `door_id`. I simply just assign it to the smallest possible door).

Everything is working perfectly, but now I want to write a query that can select all lockers that have room for a new package with a given size. My problem is that I cannot just do a `JOIN` to select empty doors because the packages only know about the locker. For each locker, I basically need to do something like `Find the smallest possible door for each package, and see if the new package fits in any of the remaining doors`. I can easily write this in JavaScript like this:

```
const canFitPackage = (reservations, doors, newPackage) => {
  const sortedReservations = reservations
    .slice()
    .sort((a, b) => a.size - b.size)
    .reverse();
  const sortedDoors = doors.slice().sort((a, b) => a.size - b.size);

  for (let i = 0; i < sortedReservations.length; i++) {
    const res = sortedReservations[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < sortedDoors.length; j++) {
      const door = sortedDoors[j];
      if (door.size >= res.size) {
        sortedDoors.splice(j, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return sortedDoors.some(door => door.size >= newPackage.size);
};
```

I have spent days trying to figure out how to do this in SQL, but so far I'm out of luck. I am wondering whether this really can be done in a SQL call or whether I need to write a Postgres function. Any help appreciated.

**Update**

After hours of trying different things, I have come up with this SQL query which does it for me. I am sure this is slow and ineffective, so any input and tips appreciated.

```
WITH 
locker_doors AS (
  SELECT * FROM doors 
  --ADD INNER JOIN ON LOCKER 
  --ADD WHERE CLAUSE ON LOCKERS
),
all_combinations AS (
  SELECT locker_doors.id AS door_id, locker_doors.size AS door_size, locker_doors.locker_id, packages.id AS package_id, packages.size AS package_size
  FROM locker_doors 
  JOIN packages ON locker_doors.locker_id = packages.locker_id AND locker_doors.size >= packages.size
  ORDER BY packages.size DESC, locker_doors.size ASC
), 
distinct_doors AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (door_id) * FROM all_combinations
), 
package_placements AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (package_id) * FROM distinct_doors
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (locker_id) locker_id 
FROM locker_doors 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT door_id FROM package_placements)
```

Comment: How *would* you write it in javascript?   That would make it very clear what exactly you're trying to do... I'm a little vague on step 2.

Comment: Also - you might investigate [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql.html) for more complex tasks.

Comment: @Dave The requirement is not clear to me either, but the best solution will probably be an SQL query.

Comment: @Dave Updated the question with working JS code.

Comment: I have realized that the SQL query model is simply not set up for this type of problem, and it would be extremely complicated to make this happen without using foreign keys.

Comment: Can you please add some example data and expected results? I think that would help me understand the problem better.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean `Find the smallest possible door for each package` would need to be calculated across *all* lockers every time a reservation is made?  Perhaps it would be useful to maintain an ideal mapping of packages to doors each time a new package is assigned to a locker so that you can easily query the remaining doors?  (You'd need to have the ability to finalize the reservation, of course, when the time comes).  I agree with @Corion; some sample data would be helpful.

Comment: Agreed sample date would make this more clear.  But the one thing that sticks out to me is you probably want to carry the door_id on Packages not locker_id.  If you do that your issue is a lot easier in all of your queries etc.  To get the locker_id if needed you would simply join doors and get the locker.  Typically your relationship should be at the most discrete level, in this case door.  Because otherwise you really don't know what fits in a locker because the door is actually the limiting size not locker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calculated column to sort remaining space of `doors` records and get the smallest one.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a8840/2

```
 WITH newPackage (packsize) as (
   values (1)--I used with clause to declare the new package. You can change the size of the new package from here to test different cases
)
select  d.*, 
(d.size - coalesce((select p.size from packages p where  p.locker_id = d.locker_id), 0)) remaining_size 
from 
doors d, 
newPackage
where 
d.size - coalesce((select p.size from packages p where  p.locker_id = d.locker_id), 0) >= newPackage.packsize
order by 
(d.size - coalesce((select p.size from packages p where  p.locker_id = d.locker_id), 0)) 
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
locker_doors AS (
  SELECT * FROM doors 
  --ADD INNER JOIN ON LOCKER 
  --ADD WHERE CLAUSE ON LOCKERS
),
all_combinations AS (
  SELECT locker_doors.id AS door_id, locker_doors.size AS door_size, locker_doors.locker_id, packages.id AS package_id, packages.size AS package_size
  FROM locker_doors 
  JOIN packages ON locker_doors.locker_id = packages.locker_id AND locker_doors.size >= packages.size
  ORDER BY packages.size DESC, locker_doors.size ASC
), 
distinct_doors AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (door_id) * FROM all_combinations
), 
package_placements AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (package_id) * FROM distinct_doors
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (locker_id) locker_id 
FROM locker_doors 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT door_id FROM package_placements)
```